# I can't get the length of the data I call with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I get an error when I call data in a new useEffect. I tried new useEffect but not working. What I want to do is map this data in useEffect and set it into the state. I will send this state as parameter.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    const reqObj = {
      page: "1",
      size: "10",
      sort_field: "id",
    };
    getWalkthroughs(reqObj)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response?.success) {
          setData(response?.data?.writeups);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });

  }, []);

console.log(data) //working
console.log(data.length) //length error
```

Comment: `data` is initially undefined; you can't call `.length` on undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "length error" I suspect you mean something like "can not read properties of undefined".

---

The initial state value is `undefined`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

So you can't access any properties on it.  You can use optional chaining so it only tries to access the property if the object exists:

```
console.log(data?.length);
```

Or only conditionally try to access it:

```
if (data) {
  console.log(data.length);
}
```

Or give the state value an initial empty array:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect() run after every render() so console.log() run before the data is set, so it run to error can not read property of underfined.